# Helm: Cannot overwrite table with non table for tls

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

this is most likely really simple but I can't figure it out for 2 hours now. I have the following Consul Ingress that I want to parameterize through a parent chart:

```
spec:
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.uiIngress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ . }}
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: {{ $serviceName }}
              servicePort: {{ $servicePort }}
  {{- end -}}
  {{- if .Values.uiIngress.tls }}
  tls:
{{ toYaml .Values.uiIngress.tls | indent 4 }}
  {{- end -}}
{{- end }}
```

I want to parameterize `spec.tls` in the above.

In the `values.yaml` file for Consul we have the following template for it:

```
uiIngress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
  hosts: []
  tls: {}
```

The closest I got to parameterizing it is the following:

```
  uiIngress:
    tls:
    - hosts:
      - "some.domain.com"
    secretName: "ssl-default"
```

When I do that I get this error though:

`warning: cannot overwrite table with non table for tls (map[])`

Can someone please help, I tried a million things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `helm` version. I think there were some issues in the old version. This one is fine:

```
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9.1", GitCommit:"20adb27c7c5868466912eebdf6664e7390ebe710", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9.1", GitCommit:"20adb27c7c5868466912eebdf6664e7390ebe710", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

I followed exactly the step you mentioned:

1. Added consul as a subchart (in `charts/consul`)
2. In the parent chart created `values.yaml` with:

   ```
   consul:
     uiIngress:
       tls:
       - hosts:
         - "some.domain.com"
       secretName: "ssl-default"
   ```
3. Helm install the parent chart

Comment: Ah, it's a live production cluster so upgrading it will be a bit tricky but since it's working on 2.9.1 we'll look into that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

If your default configuration values for this chart that are defined in the `values.yaml` file for Consul has this structure:

```
uiIngress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
  hosts: []
  tls: {}
```

And when you are executing `helm` command you are sending values like this:

```
  uiIngress:
    tls:
    - hosts:
      - "some.domain.com"
    secretName: "ssl-default"
```

The error `warning: cannot overwrite table with non table for tls (map[])` is happening because of the fact that `tls` is defined as a dict `{}` in the `values.yaml` and you are trying to set value with the type list `[]`(`- hosts:`) to it.
To fix the warning you can change provided `values.yaml` format to:

```
uiIngress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
  tls:
  - hosts: []
```

Comment: `tls:` should not have an empty array on it, if it is a dict. `uiIngress.tls.hosts` is an array... `uiIngress.tls` is a dict. `uiIngress.tls.secretName` otherwise cannot be set

Comment: In the question `uiIngress.tls` is expected to be an array. `secretName` is the key of `uiIngress` dict.